# 4 Bit Adder using port maps

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

So I am trying to do a 4 bit adder and have ran into an error I can't seem to figure out.

Error (10430): VHDL Primary Unit Declaration error at adder1.vhd(3): primary unit "Adder1Vhd" already exists in library "work"

I have a project called 4 bit adder and inside that project folder is the .vhd file for Adder1.vhd.  Here is the codes I have, if somebody could help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated.

Adder4.vhd:

```
LIBRARY IEEE; 
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; 

ENTITY Adder4 IS
  GENERIC(CONSTANT N: INTEGER := 4);
  PORT(
    a, b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0); -- Input SW[7..4]: a[3..0] inputs,
                                             -- SW[3..0]: b[3..0]
    cIn: in std_logic;
    sum: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0); -- Output LEDR[3..0]
    cOut: OUT STD_LOGIC -- Output LEDR[4]
  );
END Adder4;

ARCHITECTURE imp OF Adder4 IS
  COMPONENT Adder1 
    PORT(
      a, b, cIn : in STD_LOGIC;
      sum, cOut : out STD_LOGIC);
  END COMPONENT;
  SIGNAL carry_sig: std_logic_vector(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN

  A1: Adder1 port map (a(0), b(0), cIn, sum(0), carry_sig(0));
  A2: Adder1 port map (a(1), b(1), carry_sig(0), sum(1), carry_sig(1));
  A3: Adder1 port map (a(2), b(2), carry_sig(1), sum(2), carry_sig(2));
  A4: Adder1 port map (a(3), b(3), carry_sig(2), sum(3), cOut);

END imp;
```

Adder1.vhd(the file inside the Adder4 project folder):

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

entity Adder1Vhd is 
  port( 
    a, b, cIn : in std_logic; 
    sum, cOut : out std_logic);
end Adder1Vhd; 

architecture imp of Adder1Vhd is 
begin 
  -- Add two lines (one for sum and the other for cOut) of VHDL code here
  sum <= (a xor b) xor cIn;
  cOut <= (a and b) or (cIn and (a xor b));
end imp;
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about Altera's tools, a little googling revealed [Error (10430): VHDL Primary Unit Declaration:already exists in library "work";](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=30360), which sounds like your source files get registered into the project, and there's another primary unit with the same name.  The solution would be to remove the older design file (and/or de-register it) or change the entity name.

Comment: Also see [VHDL Primary Unit Declaration error at <location>: primary unit"<name>" already exists in library "<name>"](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_vhdl_primary_unit_exists.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another file that has an entity named `Adder1Vhd` in the library work (current work library). You can either delete the file on disk or just remove it from the library work in the file navigator of  Quartus II.

By the way, it's a good convention to save a VHDL files using the same name as the entity.

And the name of a component must be the name of it's entity, not the filename. So,

```
COMPONENT Adder1  -- here 'Adder1' should be 'Adder1Vhd' 
  PORT(
    a, b, cIn : in STD_LOGIC;
    sum, cOut : out STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;
```

Component instantiation statements are the same.