# How to implement a 4 bits adder with registers

Tags: vhdl

[image: block diagram]

How can I implement the architecture of a 4 bits adder with registers? I hope you can understand better what I am asking with this diagram

**EDIT 1:**

**When the reset signal is 1, the register r1 gets 0001 and the register r2 gets 0000**

```
LIBRARY IEEE; 
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; 

ENTITY 4bitsAdder IS
GENERIC(CONSTANT N: INTEGER := 4);
PORT(
reset :  IN STD_LOGIC; --is this correct?
clock : IN STD_LOGIC; -- is this correct?
r1, r2: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);  
sum: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0); 
output: OUT STD_LOGIC 
);
END 4bitsAdder;

ARCHITECTURE imp OF 4bitsAdder IS
 COMPONENT adds 
 PORT(
    r1, r2, cIn : in STD_LOGIC;
    sum, output : out STD_LOGIC);
    END COMPONENT;
      SIGNAL carry_sig: std_logic_vector(N DOWNTO 0);
    BEGIN
       -- How can I do this?
   END imp;
```

Comment: `r1` and `r2` are not supposed to be inputs. The only inputs are `clock` and `reset`. And `sum` is not supposed to be an output. The only output is `output`. You also don't need a carry signal.

Comment: Did you learn how to model a single register yet?

Comment: What would r1, r2 and sum be then? No, I didn't learn how to model a single register yet, I thought I knew the concept but now I don't know

Comment: In your Fibonacci sequencer (the reset values give it away)   R1,  R2 and sum don't appear to be ports in your block diagram.  They can be internal signals of an array type with the index range of the 4 bit adder or  output which is an array type length 4.  You can either instantiate 4 single bit adders connects as a 4 bit adder or use a generate statement to do so or create and instantiate a 4 bit adder. R1 is assigned to output.

Comment: @user1155120 can you answer this stack with the implementation of this 4 single bit adders that you mentioned? it would help a lot

Comment: There are several close votes on this question as [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). ***Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:*** "3. Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." The idea is twofold. That future readers can understand specific problems and answers, and those asking homework questions don't benefit from having assignments done for them.

Comment: You can use the stackoverflow search bar with search terms *[vhdl] 4 bit adder port map* where the first question by relevance [4 Bit Adder using port maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862056/4-bit-adder-using-port-maps) shows the structure of a 4 bit adder (with a carry-in which would be set to '0' in the least significant adder).  Another question by the same user [4 bit adder in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794131/4-bit-adder-in-vhdl) has an answer with a generate statement (also needing the LS carry-in set to '0'). Check out Bill Lynch's block diagram.

Comment: The design can also be implemented behaviorally, the 'hint' that you using a design hierarchy comes from the component declaration for adds which is a one bit adder whose carry-out appears to be the output port `output`, and you've named the two inputs r1, and r2 (not confused with the ports of a 4 bit adder, primary design units are analyzed (compiled) independently). You've either missed something in classes or your curriculum is lacking. The Stackoverflow failure is a lack of timely moderation (close votes) to move you toward providing a specific question.